# Sequlize Project With Node js on type module and run seeders

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

currently in order to run seeders i have to change the dirctory to the db folder then i need to change packgejson `type:module` to `type:commonjs` and only then run the sequlize seeder script
`npx sequelize db:seed --seed src/db/seeders/000-updates.js`

after any change i need to back to my root directory and change to `type:module`

how can i update seeders directly from my root directory and without change packege json all the time?.

i thought to write  a new script on packge json but i dont know how to?

Comment: You use `ES native modules`, am I right?

Comment: Yes, im using esmodule

Comment: One way is to change extensions of main modules to `mjs` and keep seeder's extensions as . `js`

Comment: And of course you need a proper config for Sequelize CLI so it can find seeders in the `seeders` folder

Comment: if i understand u correctly , i think i already did it (i created packege.json with type:commonjs in seeders folder and remain the esmodule in root folder) if this is what u mean. it working, currently i not change the packge json each time. but i have to change directory to seeder folder instead to run it from root folder

Comment: You need to indicate in the Sequelize CLI config that seeders path is not the root folder but the `seeders` subfolder.

Comment: And I meant one `package.json` in the root folder, of course.

Comment: @Anatoly ,Can u tell me example how do i change Sequlize CLI config path ? (curently the config is basic with properties of dev,test,production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to customize the Sequelize CLI configuration you need to add `.sequelizerc` file in the root folder and its content could be like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  'config': './db/config.json',
  'migrations-path': './db/migrations',
  'models-path': './db/models',
  'seeders-path': './db/seeders'
}
```